# Merge two or more lists in a list?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have two queries. I want to assign the list values ​​returned from these two queries to a single list, send it to the view and meet it in the view. My goal is to learn to work with lists in C#.

```
var list1 = c.ETs.Where(p => p.prop != "yes").ToList();
var list2 = c.ETs.Where(p => p.prop == "yes").ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't even need to be two queries, you could do `c.ETs.ToList()` or if you want to have two different clauses that aren't simply opposites: `ct.ETs.Where(p => p.prop == "yes" || p.prop == "no").ToList()` for example

Comment: If you combine these 2 lists, you will only get the initial List `c.ETs` which you already have.

Comment: Not the solution for me, because I'm displaying two different tables in html

Comment: ct.ETs.Where(p => p.prop == "yes" || p.prop == "no").ToList()
This query select all data in db.  Then how can i select data "yes" while displaying html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge two lists into one with this:

```
var newList = List1
    .Concat(List2)
    .ToList();
```

Though you could drop the `ToList` and work directly with the `IEnumerable` which means you don't need to create a new object.

However, this doesn't even need to be two queries since the Where clauses of both are opposite so they include the entire table, you could do:

```
var list = c.ETs.ToList();
```

Or if you want to have two different clauses that aren't simply opposites:

```
var list = ct.ETs
    .Where(p => p.prop == "yes" || p.prop == "no")
    .ToList()` for example
```

Comment: I need send this list view also access to data for foreach looping

Answer (score 0):

This will combine the values of both lists in a single list (the final output will be stored in `List1`):

```
List1.AddRange(List2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ahmet you can try something like this but note you will need Linq:

`var list3 = List1.Concat(List2).ToList();`

or if you have more than 2 lists:

```
var list3 = list1.Concat(list2)
                              .Concat(list3)
                              .ToList();
```

Another method:

`var list3 = List1.AddRange(List2);`

Both above will create a new list containing both lists' items.

Comment: _Note_: `.Where()` clause is already Linq :)

Comment: :) But in view, I have two columns  which is YES and NO. So I must have two different query and send view one list for non using model or view model